# Insert a certain number of characters with spaces included

Tags: c

What I'm trying to accomplish is to take no more than "x" characters (spaces included) as input. I only know how to do both of them separately with `scanf`,

like the following:

```
scanf("%20s",str)
```

This takes no more than 20 characters.

`scanf("%[^\n]s",str)` takes spaces as well, but it has no limit.
I tried `getline` but it takes the `\n` as a value in the string as well and I don't want that. I hope I was clear enough about what I'm asking.

From what @chqrlie has told me I wrote this fuction:

```
void getstring(char *str, int len)
{
    do
    {
        if (fgets(str, len, stdin))
        {
            fflush(stdin);
// if is not the first character to be the new line then change it to '\0' which is the end of the string.
            if (str[0] != '\n')
                str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';
        }
    }while (str[0] == '\n'); // Check if the user has inserted a new line as first character
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried already

Comment: I'm sorry, it still takes more than 20 characters

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that. Anyway, I just realized that it works, but another problem has occured. The new vector of chars will be appended to the last one for no reason after the 20 characters.

Comment: I tried to open another project and check the code, it works fine, I need to find out where my main project is bugged, thank you for the help.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, again thank your for the explanation, that clarifies everything.

Comment: Why not combine your approaches - use a field width with `%[` like this: `%20[^\n]`.

Comment: Please remove the `fflush(stdin);`. It is useless and has undefined behavior. Also you must break from the loop if `fgets()` returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

The format for character classes does **not** have a trailing `s`, it is written this way:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", str)
```

If you wish to limit the maximum number of characters stored into the destination array, specify this number between the `%` and the `[`:

```
scanf("%20[^\n]", str)
```

Note however that the conversion will fail and `scanf()` will return `0` if there is an empty line pending for this conversion specification.

It is a common mistake to omit the test on the return value of `scanf()`, causing undefined behavior in case of conversion failures because the destination variables are left in their previous state (uninitialized in many cases).

It may be more effective to use `fgets()` and remove the trailing newline this way:

```
if (fgets(s, 20, stdin)) {
    /* line was read, can be an empty line */
    s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';  /* remove the trailing newline if any */
    ...
} else {
    /* fgets() failed, either at end-of-file or because of I/O error */
    ...
}
```

Comment: The first solution that you are giving me was suggested by someone in the comments yesterday, but I'm looking right now and I think the user deleted his messages. I managed to solve my problem by using "scanf("%20[^\n]", str)", but I'd like to change it as a function, that's why I'll try out the second solution suggested by you, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I don't know how to update my question by putting the solution, the second one works like a charm, thank you so much.

Comment: I only need to solve the last problem, I don't want to take '\n' as first value of input, how do I check that?

Comment: @GeneNight:  There is no need to modify the question to add a solution or a solved remark. Regarding how to treat empty lines, you can test if the line is empty after stripping the newline: `if (*s == '\0') { printf("invalid input\n"); return 1; }` and test the return value at the calling point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
for(i = 0; i < x; i++) 
{
    getchar(c);
    if(c == '\n') break;
    str[i] = c; 
}
```

But you must have to be aware of the existing newlines in the buffer. :)